# for which values of "a" does the system have one, zero, or infinite solutions? [SOLVED]

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Question:
[image]

I'm having trouble solving this, I've looked everywhere for a similar question but this one doesn't seem to follow the rules of other questions. after Gauss-Jordan elimination I end up with.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&2&1&2\\
      0&-6&1&-3\\0&0&2-a^2&a-2
    \end{array}
\right] $$

the issue I'm really having is finding when the system has infinite solutions. Please help

[EDIT] This has been solved, there are NO values of "a" for which the system has infinite solutions.

Comment: The system would have infinitely many solutions if the last row was all zeroes in this case.  Is it possible to find a value of $a$ where $2-a^2=0$ and $a-2=0$ simultaneously?  In a similar vein, the system will have zero solutions if you have a row of all zeroes on the left but a nonzero number on the right.  Is it possible to find a value of $a$ where $2-a^2=0$ but $a-2\neq 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deteminant which is equal to$$-6 (2-a^2) $$ must be zero.
this gives $a=\pm \sqrt{2} $.

but in this case $a-2\neq 0$.

we conclude that

if $a\neq \pm \sqrt{2} $, there is one solution

if $a=\pm \sqrt {2} $, there is no solution.

Comment: But what about for when the system has infinite solutions? the last row of the matrix would have to be all zeroes, but that's impossible. is it possible that the answer is "there is never infinite solutions"?

Comment: @M.Bucciacchio Yes of course.

Comment: oh goodness me, I was stuck on this forever thinking that I HAD to find a solution, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &1 \\ 
 2&-2  &3 \\ 
1 &2  & 3-a^{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
1\\ 
a
\end{pmatrix}$.

$detA=6(a^2-2)$.

Case 1: $det(A) \neq 0$
Then the system has unique solution $\Leftrightarrow a\in \mathbb{R}-\left \{ \pm \sqrt{2} \right \}$

Case 2: $det(A)=0 \Leftrightarrow a=\left \{\pm \sqrt{2} \right \}$
We have $d=\begin{vmatrix}
1 &2 \\ 
 2&-2 
\end{vmatrix}=-6 \neq 0$, so $rank(A)=2$

But $d_{char}=\begin{vmatrix}
1 &2  &2 \\ 
 2&-2  & 1\\ 
 1&2  &\pm \sqrt{2} 
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0$, hence the system has no solution

Answer (score 0):

Note: JMoravitz's comment on the row echelon form gave all necessary clues for 1. and 3.

1. There is no solution if there is an inconsistent equation, i.e. all zero coefficents for the unknowns left vs. non-zero inhomogenity right.
   Only possible in the last row, iff
   $$
   2-a^2 = 0 \wedge a-2 \ne 0 \iff \\
   a = \pm\sqrt{2} \wedge a \ne 2
   $$
   So this is the case for $a =\pm\sqrt{2}$.
2. There is one solution if the matrix has full rank, which is the case for
   $$
   2-a^2\ne 0 \iff \\
   a \ne \pm\sqrt{2}
   $$
3. There are infinite many solutions if there is at least one empty row with zero inhomogenity to be consistent. This is only possible for the last row, iff
   $$
   2-a^2 = 0 \wedge a-2=0 \iff \\
   a = \pm\sqrt{2} \wedge a=2
   $$
   which is not possible.