# For what value of "a" does the following system: i) have no solution, ii) have infinitely many solutions, iii) have a unique solution??*

Tags: linear-algebra

System is:

```
ax + y + z = 1
x + ay + z = 1
x + y + az = 1
```

I need to find the answer using matrices and reduced echelon form :) 
How do I even get to a reduced echelon form to be able to solve this system?

Any help understanding is appreciated!

Comment: Have look at this site here how to do it, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250457/for-which-values-of-a-does-the-system-have-one-zero-or-infinite-solutions?rq=1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381580/for-what-values-of-a-does-the-resulting-system-have-a-no-solution-b-a-uni).

Comment: Just looking at this, I suspect you want to consider $a=-2$ and $a=1$ and all other values of $a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes easily from Cramer’s rule (and even easier from inspection, but for the sake of matrices).

Let 
$$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix} a&1&1\\1&a&1\\1&1&a\end{vmatrix}$$

For a unique solution $\Delta$ is not singular.

$$\Delta = a(a^2-1) - (a-1) + 1-a$$
$$= a(a+1)(a-1)-2(a-1)=(a-1)(a^2+a-2) = (a-1)^2(a+2)$$

So there is a unique solution for $a \neq 1, -2$.

$\bf{For~a=1:}$
$$\Delta = \Delta_x = \Delta_y = \Delta_z = \begin{vmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1 \end{vmatrix} = 0$$ so there are infinite solutions (the system is the plane $x+y+z=1$)

$\bf{For~a=-2:}$

$$\Delta_x = \begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\1&-2&1\\1&1&-2\end{vmatrix} = 9$$

So the system has no solutions for $a = -2$.

To recap:

$$\boxed{\sf{The~system~is~inconsistent~if~a=-2,~underdetermined~if~a=1,~and~has~a~unique~solution~otherwise.}}$$

Answer (score 2):

First put this into matrix form:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
a &1  &1  &1 \\ 
 1& a &1  &1 \\ 
 1& 1 &a  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not going to go over how to row reduce, there are many tutorials online.
(https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m8s00/public_html/handouts/matrices/node7.html)

In row echelon form:
$$M\sim [A|b]=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0  &0  &\frac{1}{a+2} \\ 
 0& 1&0  &\frac{1}{a+2}\\ 
 0& 0&1  &\frac{1}{a+2}
\end{bmatrix}_{RREF}$$

For **no solutions**: $\text{rank}(A|b)>\text{rank}[A]$, no values of $a$ satisfy this.

For a **unique solution** $\text{rank}(A|b)=\text{rank}[A]=3$.
So, $\frac{1}{a+2}\neq 0$, so $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

For **infinite solutions** $\text{rank}(A|b)=\text{rank}[A]<3$. No value of $a$ satisfies this either.

So for $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $M$ has a unique solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! I still have some questions left, though. For example, you don't seem to have reached the Reduced Echelon Form in your solution. You have only reached the Echelon Form. Does this make any difference?

Comment: I guess you made a mistake with your matrix. a = 1 does give infinitely many answers.

Comment: @SelinKöksal for most uses of RREF, REF will work just as well. However, when dealing with coefficients as well as numbers, REF leaves us with a much more "human-friendly" matrix.

Comment: I have the correct form for RREF, however yes, the infinite solution a=1 does not seem obvious when looking at the $\text{rank}(A|b)=\text{rank}[A]<3$ definition. If anyone can edit my answer, would be very greatful.

Comment: Hi again, how can you divide rows of a matrix by "a" when you don't know whether a=0 or not?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating $x$ we get
$$(a-1)(y-z)=0$$